# How does one update a prefect Flow with duplicate parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prefect

Using [prefect](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/core/flow.html#flow-2), I would like to create a new flow from two other flows.

[image] [image]

The error I am getting is `A task with the slug "add_num" already exists in this flow.` Is it possible to update `Flows` that use the same `tasks` or `Parameters`. Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to accomplish. 
`

```
from prefect import task, Flow, Parameter

@task
def add_one(x):
    return x+1

with Flow("Flow 1") as flow_1:
    add_num = Parameter("add_num", default=10)
    new_num1 = add_one(add_num)

@task
def add_two(y):
    return y+1

with Flow("Flow 2") as flow_2:
   add_num = Parameter("add_num", default=10)
   new_num2 = add_two(add_num)

 combo_fl = Flow("Add Numbers")

 combo_fl.update(flow_1)
 combo_fl.update(flow_2, validate=False)
```

I did see this piece of code on the slack channel that might tie into solving this problem but I am not sure how to use it.

```
class GlobalParameter(Parameter):
    def __init__(self, name, slug=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = slug or uuid.uuid4()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Parameters are uniquely identified by name in the API, you can't combine two flows that have different Parameters of the same name.  However, what you *can* do is use a common Parameter within each flow as follows:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow, Parameter

## initialize the Parameter outside of any
## Flow context

add_num = Parameter("add_num", default=10)

@task
def add_one(x):
    return x+1

with Flow("Flow 1") as flow_1:
    new_num1 = add_one(add_num)

@task
def add_two(y):
    return y+1

with Flow("Flow 2") as flow_2:
   new_num2 = add_two(add_num)

combo_fl = Flow("Add Numbers")

combo_fl.update(flow_1)
combo_fl.update(flow_2, validate=False)
```

Because the Parameter being used is actually the same instance of the Parameter class, your update will succeed.